# TinyMCE template location

Tags: tinymce

I've scoured the documentation but to no avail.

Where is `src` looking at in the settings? Is it the root of the site or the `tiny_mce` folder?

If my template was located at: `/tiny_mce/templates/example.html`, what would I put as the SRC?

```
template_templates : [
        {
                title : "Editor Details",
                src : "editor_details.htm",
                description : "Adds Editor Name and Staff ID"
        },
        {
                title : "Timestamp",
                src : "blank.htm",
                description : "Adds an editing timestamp."
        }
],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out the the location is relative to wherever the script is run from.

So if you are calling the script on the root file (MasterPage in this instance) the code is:

```
        template_templates : [
                {
                        title : "Base Home Page",
                        src : "/tiny_mce/temp/Base.htm",
                        description : "Basic Homepage, rotate, etc.."
                }
        ],
```

So the html file is located in `./tiny_mce/temp/`